# merge two pandas data frames changes the names of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two data frames:

here is the first dataframe

```
Test | Compile Time (s) | Compile Memory Consumption () |
1    |            7.32  |                          54   |
2    |            2.46  |                         573   |
```

here is the second dataframe

```
Test | Compile Time (s) | Compile Memory Consumption () |
1    |            10.44 |                          209  |
2    |            4.43  |                          3677 |
```

And here is the merged dataframe

```
Test |  Compile Time (s)_x | Compile Memory Consumption ()_x | Compile Time (s)_y |  Compile Memory Consumption ()_y |
1    |  7.32               | 54                              | 10.44              |     209                          |
2    |  2.46               | 573                             | 4.43               |    3677                          |
```

when I try renaming the columns I get the names left shifted one column like:

```
     |  Test               | Compile Time (s)                | Compile Memory Consumption ()      |  Compile Time (s) | Compile Memory Consumption 
1    |  7.32               | 54                              | 10.44                              |     209                          |
2    |  2.46               | 573                             | 4.43          |    3677                          |
```

what could be the problem? and how to rename it correctly?

many thanks.

Comment: read the `merge` documentation, in particular the `suffixes` parameter

Comment: thanks @mozway, I edited the question since I wasn't able to solve the problem